# Right align input fields in a fluid container

Tags: css, input, fluid-layout

This should be simple but I'm having issues.

I have a fluid percentage container, I need the text input and submit to align to the right and sit next to each other.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sarah3585/bamL87d4/

Many thanks

HTML:

```
<div class="header-search">
<form>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Website"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-search {
width:95%;
float:right;
background:yellow;
}

form {
display:block;
float:right;

}

input[type='text'] {
margin:0;
padding-left:40px;
width:80%;

}

input[type='submit'] {
float:right;
padding-left:16px;
padding-right:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is okay with you,

```
input[type='text'] {
    margin:0;
    padding-left:40px;
    width:55%;
}
```

See this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/bamL87d4/2/)

Or you can simplify the whole code to,

```
.header-search {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
form {
  float: right;
}
input[type='text'] {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I am not an expert, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chendatony31/bamL87d4/3/)
Here is Mine

Because your form don't have a `width` and `input[type='text']` don't have `float`

Comment: I need to avoid a having a set width so the fluid container can flow without it dropping down. Maybe that's not possible.